# Showing that $z \mapsto z^n$ is not nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to show that the map $P_R^n : \Sigma_R \to \mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0\}}$ which sends $z$ to $z^n$, with $\Sigma_R = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \left| z \right|  = R\} $ is not nullhomotopic.

I need some help with that, here is what I think might be an idea: I thought about using the degree map, and the fact that I've previously showed that $\Sigma_R$ has the same homotopy type as $\mathbb{C}^*$. Since I know that the map $P_1^n : S^1 \to S^1: z \mapsto z^n$ has $\operatorname{deg}(P_1^n) = n$. Thus, if I suppose that $P_R^n$ is nullhomotopic, it means that we have $P_R^n \simeq k \in \mathbb{C}^*$, hence $[P_R^n] = [k]$ and it would be nice to use the homotopy equivalence between $\Sigma_R $ and $\mathbb{C}^*$, where we would restrict $\mathbb{C}^*$ to $S^1$ and use the fact that the degree of the constant map is  $0$.

Is this idea even feasible? If so, how could I make it work? What I've tried (which is probably false) is the following:

Let $\rho : \mathbb{C}^* \to \Sigma_R : z \mapsto R \frac{z}{\left| z \right| }$ with $R >0$. Now, let  $f : \mathbb{C}^* \to S^1$ be the homotopy equivalence. Now, I tried naively to define a homotopy $P_R^n \simeq P_1^n$, in order to have $[P_R^n] = [P_1^n] = [k]$, since $\operatorname{deg}([u]) = \operatorname{deg}(u) $. Then, define $H : \mathbb{C}^* \times I \to \mathbb{C}^*$, $H(z,t) = \rho (z)^n(1-t)+tf(z)^n$. Do we now have our desired equalites of equivalence classes?

I would appreciate any feedback, and perhaps a hint towards a simpler solution!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi : \mathbb{C}^* \to S^1$ be defined by $\pi(z) = z / |z|$, and let $f_R : S^1 \to \Sigma_R$ be the natural identification. Then we have
$$
P^n_1 = \pi \circ P^n_R \circ f_R
$$
as maps $S^1 \to S^1$. Thus $P^n_R$ cannot be nullhomotopic, because otherwise $P^n_1$ would also be nullhomotopic, which is not possible since $\deg(P^n_1) = n$.

Comment: Ah yes, it is basically the same thing but without using homotopies, much simpler! Thank you.